# ANTLR Parsing rule covering block of text containing the "End"-Token

Tags: parsing, antlr

I am wondering whether there is a possibility for antlr parsing rules to create rules that match Strings containing the endtoken. I'll illustrate this by using an sql-example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UFHDBTBL.FH_LIEF_SPERR_SK(pidpack INTEGER)
    ...
BEGIN ATOMIC

   DECLARE sperrsk VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT '';--
   DECLARE erster INTEGER DEFAULT 0;--
   FOR satz AS
      SELECT sk_name1
      FROM UFHDBTBL.FH01TM21 psk, UFHDBTBL.FH01T61 lsk
      WHERE psk.id_pack = pidpack          
   DO
      IF erster  =  1 THEN
         SET sperrsk = sperrsk || '<br>';--
      END IF ;--
      SET sperrsk = sperrsk || LTRIM(RTRIM(satz.sk_name1));--
      IF erster  =  0 THEN
        SET erster  = 1;--
      END IF ;--
   END FOR;--
   RETURN sperrsk;--

END;
```

Currently, I tried the following parsing-rules to match all the stuff between "BEGIN ATOMIC" and "END;":

```
'BEGIN' ~('END')    'END'
'BEGIN' .+? 'END'
'BEGIN' (~('END')|~(';'))* 'END'
(The last ; is contained in the "create function rule" so don't worry about it)
```

Notice, that the block contains the tokens "END" and ";". Since I don't want to create a new token "END;" (which causes many other rules to fail), I hope there is some antlr guy around who's able to help me!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's wrong with something like `'BEGIN' statement+ END` where `statement` contains the rule `'FOR' ID 'AS' whatever 'DO' statement+ 'END' 'IF' ';--'`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong about that rule. It's just that I don't need to dig into the content of the function and would prefer a more high-level rule like `'BEGIN' stuff 'END'` where stuff matches no matter what (including the tokens 'END' and ';'. The main problem of this question is, that I cannot introduce the new token 'END;'. If that would be possible the problem would already be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following to match everything until `END;` without creating a new single token to represent it.

```
'BEGIN'
(   ~'END'
|   'END' ~';'
)*
'END' ';'
```

Comment: the problem is, that the semicolon is handled in a parent rule. Every SQL-Statement is followed by a semicolon. I hoped there would be a way to avoid the declaration of ';' at the end of the rule.